Getting service acount credential in GKE
I have GKE cluster that uses a custom service-account. I'm using it to access Google API (Gmail API). But, when I use
final List<String> SCOPES = List.of(GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY);
GoogleCredentials delegatedCredentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()
                    .createScoped(SCOPES)
                    .createDelegated(user);
return new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, new HttpCredentialsAdapter(delegatedCredentials)).setApplicationName("Gmail-App").build();

I expected delegatedCredentials to be the attached GKE service account ServiceAccountCredentials. However, it returns a ComputeEngineCredentials which is likely the default SA that comes up with GKE. So, this causes permissions/roles issues for the next Google API calls.
I setup KSA in the deployment.yaml kubernetes config file. I create the KSA file using terraform and assign it whatever role is needed.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-services-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-services
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-services
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: my-develop-services-ksa

I've verified that service account my-develop-services-ksa@ is attached to the pods.
I want to keep using a dedicated service account where I can customize roles for it rather than attaching roles to the default GKE SA.
As a workaround, when/if I use the service account file to load the GoogleCredentials from service-account stream (file/byte), then it works as expected.
GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials
                    .fromStream(serviceAccountStream)
                    .createScoped(SCOPES).createDelegated(user);
return new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, new HttpCredentialsAdapter(delegatedCredentials)).setApplicationName("Gmail-App").build();

How can I solve this?

EDIT 1:
The service-account was setup using Workload-Identity from a terraform script
module "highpass-services-gke-workload-identity" {
  source              = "terraform-google-modules/kubernetes-engine/google//modules/workload-identity"
  name                = "${var.project_services}-ksa"
  namespace           = "default"
  project_id          = var.project
  roles               = []
  gcp_sa_display_name = "Develop Services GKE - SA/KSA"
}


You should consider using Workload Identity Federation for GKE. This allows a Kubernetes Service Account to be bound to a Google Cloud (IAM) Service Account such that Kubernetes Resources credentialed to the Kubernetes Service Account is able to leverage the bound Service Account's permissions.

I used Workload Identity to set it up using Terraform. I've added Edit 1 to show that. GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault() still picks up ComputeEngineCredentials. I've done the whole kubectl get pod/pod-name -o yaml and it shows ksa file as the service account.

I suspect it's more likely that Workload Identity Federation isn't correctly configured and it's falling back to the Compute Engine default Service Account than the Java SDK isn't correctly acquiring the credentials. Have you tried running your code/container outside of GKE and with GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/key.json  to eliminate the SDK?

I tried it when I was building the app and to use the Google APIs from a local machine, and it works. I was pointing to the service account that GKE is supposed to be using. It feels like I'm missing something somewhere.

Yes, Kubernetes Service Accounts are constrained to Kubernetes. When you run the code using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS you provide the Google Cloud (IAM) Service Account key. And GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault() finds it. When you run the same code on Kubernetes, ADC uses Workload Identity  to get the (same Google Cloud IAM) credentials associated with the Kubernetes Service Account. That the code worked off-cloud strongly suggests WIF is configured incorrectly.
